# How to find dir with least depth?

Tags: bash, shell

How to find a dir with least depth? Below script finds the dir `bb` with least depth, but I think there should be better way/one liner? here it prints the path with least number of `/`s in it.

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── bb
│       └── c
│           └── d
│               └── bb
├── m
│   └── n
│       └── k
│           └── bb
└── x
    └── y
        └── bb
            └── z

n=100
for f in $(find . -name bb -type d); do
  l=$(echo $f | tr -cd '/' | wc -c)
  if [[ $l -lt $n ]]; then
     n=$l
     shortest_bb=$f
  fi  
done
echo $shortest_bb
```

Comment: Maybe adapt https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279895/how-can-i-do-a-breadth-first-search-using-find

Comment: What's that in relation to? `sort` definitely sorts reliably, though it has usability problems which may produce unexpected results when you use it incorrectly.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, not related to your comments, but was asking in general.

Comment: "In general" is too general to be answerable. :) -- if character collation order or encoding is uncontrolled, `sort`'s output may differ from what's expected or would occur with other settings, but correct/robust usage controls for that. Which is to say, `sort` is unreliable only if you use it without knowing what you're doing. :)

Comment: Got it, thanks @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are allowed in "one-liners":

```sh
# set up the test directories
mkdir -p a/bb/c/d/bb m/n/k/bb x/y/bb/z

# and find the shortest "bb" path
find . -type d -name bb |
  awk -F/ '{print NF "\t" $0}' |
  sort -k1,1n |
  head -1 |
  cut -f2
```

```
./a/bb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one liner :

```
find . -type d | awk '{ print gsub(/\//,$0) " " $0 }' | sort -rn
```

And it will output the *depth* on the first column :

```
   5 /test/test.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Matias-Barrios.xcuserdatad/xcschemes
   5 ./test/test.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/Matias-Barrios.xcuserdatad
   5 ./TestQueue/TestQueue.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Matias-Barrios.xcuserdatad/xcschemes
   5 ./TestQueue/TestQueue.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Matias-Barrios.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger
   4 ./TestQueue/TestQueue/Assets.xcassets/seven.imageset
   4 ./TestQueue/TestQueue/Assets.xcassets/question.imageset
   4 ./TestQueue/TestQueue/Assets.xcassets/poker.imageset
```

And so on.
Hope it helps

Comment: Why would you put the depth on the *second* column rather than the first? Easier to sort on the first column, and that way you don't have tools misread what constitutes the "second" column if your filenames contain spaces and/or numbers (wouldn't want the part of the name after the space to be read as the second column).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right. That's a bad order. I'll correct it. Thanks